# Theoretical supporting factors to consider neutrinos are majorana type particles or dirac type particles

Tags: neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, majorana-fermions

What are the theoretical supportive factors to consider neutrinos as Dirac fermions? What are the theoretical supportive factors to consider neutrinos as Majorana fermions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148042/50583

Comment: my question is not whether neutrinos are majorana type particle or dirac particle,my question is that what are theoretical supporting factors to consider neutrinos are majorana type and same goes to  dirac type also.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "theoretical supporting factors"?

Comment: for example in the case of majorana type, one can say the see-saw mechanism is a theoretical supporting factor.